# Connecting a Wireless Access Point to a modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I don't have a router. The modem works perfectly (Arris TM1602) with wired connections. The access point (Trendnet TEW-230APB) is broadcasting the SSID, but my laptop cannot connect to the wireless internet.

When I try to connect my laptop to the WiFi, it says "Failed to Obtain IP address". Should the Wireless AP have a different IP address than the modem itself? Even when I set the Wireless AP to get the IP address automatically, my laptop still cannot connect to the WiFi.

What am I doing wrong? According to the manual for the AP, a router is not needed. I don't have a router so I thought I could connect and configure the AP to broadcast the wireless internet throughout the house.

Comment: Very often, your modem _is_ also a router. Your computer obtains a 192.168.x IP address from it, doesn't it? (Direct connection without a router is much less common nowadays than it used to be.)

Comment: My modem is not a router -it's just a modem. When I go to IPCONFIG it says my ethernet IP address on my PC (which is wired to the modem) is 24.181.x.x

Comment: Well, in that case, you can only connect as many devices as your ISP gives addresses – for residential connections, usually just one. (That's why most people use a router with NAT function – to share one address between multiple devices.)

Comment: Most modems are routers. You have to change the mode from "bridge" to "NAT" which might require a special password depending on your model.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you do not have a DHCP server connected to the network and the AP is taking the one IP address you are allotted by your ISP.  That is why your computer is complaining that it cannot obtain an address.  Normally, one's router would act as a separate DHCP server, but since you do not have a router and your AP cannot act as a DHCP server, there is no server to assign more addresses.

There is really only one way to fix this:  Buy a wireless router which can act as a DHCP server (which is basically all of them).  This also has the added advantage of allowing you to connect more than one device to the Internet at a time.  Plus, that AP appears to be very old and slow, and even lower end routers will probably be a better bet.